# How often does the Bluetooth and Wifi Mac address change? How can I get notified?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, nfc, multipeer-connectivity, ios11

I am using [multi-peer networking](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity), HotSpot Helper APIs, and standard NSUrlsession.

I broadcast an identifier that should also be randomized in concert with any iOS managed address changing.

**Question**

- How can I get notified that a MAC address changed? (Wifi, MAC address, or  NFC in iOS 11)
- It may or may not be possible, but there are cases where I need to know what the new address is

Comment: Can the MAC address even change on non-jailbroken iPhone?

Comment: @Losiowaty Yes, it changes per SSID and routinely while broadcasting searching for a access point

Comment: Out of curiosity - can you provide any source for that? It would be strange for a device to change its MAC address because it connected to a router. Are you talking about MAC address as described here : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address ? Also, to be clear, you want to detect a change of iPhones WiFi MAC address, or of the access point it is connected to?

Answer (score 0):

Neither can you know if the MAC has changed nor can you find out the new MAC. That's the whole point of MAC Randomization (introduced in iOS 8): Security.

The exact time interval when the MAC changes rests with the manufacturer, as stated in the BT official website:
https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/bluetooth-technology-protecting-your-privacy/

> To safeguard user privacy, manufacturers can make use of a Bluetooth
>   Smart feature known as “LE Privacy.” This feature causes the MAC
>   address within the advertising packets to be replaced with a random
>   value that changes at timing intervals determined by the manufacturer.
>   Any malicious device(s), placed at intervals along your travel route,
>   would not be able to determine that the series of different, randomly
>   generated MAC addresses received from your device actually relates to
>   the same physical device. It actually looks like a series of different
>   devices, thus, it will not be possible to track you using the
>   advertised MAC address.

Note: MAC only changes when scanning for Wi-Fi access points. It will not change when the device is in active connection.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the MAC should not change, at least not without hefty Jailbreak Tweaks which with newer semi-untethered paradigm wouldn't work either. The MAC address just like the serial number, are unique device IDs that are not supposed to ever change.

The MAC address is a unique ID assigned to a networking component. While jailbreaks can change it, normal iOS usage would never.